# Controlled Serial Data Transmission from Arduino Using GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

I am trying to create a Python GUI that makes the Arduino start transmission when 1 is pressed and stop transmission when anything else(say 0) is pressed. The code I've written (below) works perfectly for the first start and stop but fails to work for the next time I hit start.
My Python Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import time

import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    print (p)
    if "Serial Device" in str(p):
        print("Connect here!")
        wor=str(p)
        w=wor[:4]
        print(w)

ser = serial.Serial(w, 9600)


ser.write('0'.encode())


def start1():
    ser.write('1'.encode())
    global count_flag1
    count_flag1 = True
    count = str(ser.readline())
    while True:
        if count_flag1 == False:
            break
        s=count.split(",")
        p=s[0].split("'")
        s[0]=p[1]
        # put the count value into the label
        label1['text'] = "A0:"+s[0]+" A1:"+s[1]+" A2:"+s[2]
        # wait for 0.1 seconds
        #time.sleep(1)
        # needed with time.sleep()
        root.update()
        # increase count
        count = str(ser.readline())

def stop1():
    global count_flag1
    count_flag1 = False
    ser.write('0'.encode())



# create a Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
# this will be a global flag
count_flag1 = True


# create needed widgets
label1 = tk.Label(root, text='l1')
btn_start1 = tk.Button(root, text='start all', command=start1)
btn_stop1 = tk.Button(root, text='stop all', command=stop1)
# use a grid to place the widgets
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
btn_start1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
btn_stop1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
```

My Arduino Code:

```
int oldv;
int newv;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    newv=(Serial.read());
    if(newv=='1'){
      //newv=1;
      Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(analogRead(A1));
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(analogRead(A2));
      Serial.println(",");
      oldv=1;}
    else{
       oldv=0;
    }
    delay(500);
  }
   else{
    newv=oldv;
        if(newv==1){
          Serial.print(analogRead(A0));
          Serial.print(",");
          Serial.print(analogRead(A1));
          Serial.print(",");
          Serial.print(analogRead(A2));
          Serial.println(",");
          oldv=1;}
        else{
           oldv=0;
        }
        delay(500);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have made a very common mistake with tkinter programs. NEVER have an infinite loop. Your code will be getting stuck in the loop inside `start1` and will never return. Also you don't have a call to tkinter `.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using while Ture with tkinter is big red flag. And to use rule of a thumb newer use it ;)
Best way to refresh tkinter is function after()

```py
import tkinter as tk
from time import time

import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    print (p)
    if "Serial Device" in str(p):
        print("Connect here!")
        wor=str(p)
        w=wor[:4]
        print(w)

ser = serial.Serial(w, 9600)


ser.write('0'.encode())


def start1():
    ser.write('1'.encode())
    ref = root.after(100, refresh) #runs function refresh every 100ms


def stop1():
    if ref != None:
       root.cancle(ref)
       ser.write('0'.encode())

def refresh():
    # increase count
    count = str(ser.readline())
    s=count.split(",")
    p=s[0].split("'")
    s[0]=p[1]
    # put the count value into the label
    label1['text'] = "A0:"+s[0]+" A1:"+s[1]+" A2:"+s[2]
    # wait for 0.1 seconds

# create a Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()

#global va, prepared for after function
ref =None

# create needed widgets
label1 = tk.Label(root, text='l1')
btn_start1 = tk.Button(root, text='start all', command=start1)
btn_stop1 = tk.Button(root, text='stop all', command=stop1)
# use a grid to place the widgets
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
btn_start1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
btn_stop1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)

#mainloop() is better way of running tkinter GUI. It is similar to function   .update() in while
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Although this works, this isn't exactly the functionality I'm after. I need the Arduino to start transmitting (and displaying) values continually after I press start. Both the transmission and display must stop after anything else is pressed.

Comment: What do you mean with anything else? Every other key? Clicked anywhere else?
If you want to stop it on any other just add events when it should stop

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got it. It looks like I need to update the root for stop function as well!

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import time

import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    print (p)
    if "Serial Device" in str(p):
        print("Connect here!")
        wor=str(p)
        w=wor[:4]
        print(w)

ser = serial.Serial(w, 9600)

ser.write('0'.encode())



def start1():
    ser.write('1'.encode())
    global count_flag1
    count_flag1 = True
    count = str(ser.readline())
    #print("started")
    while True:
        if count_flag1 == False:
            break
        s=count.split(",")
        p=s[0].split("'")
        s[0]=p[1]
        # put the count value into the label
        label1['text'] = "A0:"+s[0]+" A1:"+s[1]+" A2:"+s[2]
        # wait for 0.1 seconds
        #time.sleep(1)
        # needed with time.sleep()
        root.update()
        # increase count
        count = str(ser.readline())

def stop1():
    ser.write('0'.encode())
    global count_flag1
    count_flag1 = False
    while True:
        if count_flag1 == True:
            break
        root.update()






# create a Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
# this will be a global flag
count_flag1 = True


# create needed widgets
label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Display')
btn_start1 = tk.Button(root, text='start all', command=start1)
btn_stop1 = tk.Button(root, text='stop all', command=stop1)
# use a grid to place the widgets
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
btn_start1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
btn_stop1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
```